# Setting CRS for projects and layers results in looping dialogue

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-3

After a previous issue, I uninstalled (`sudo apt remove qgis`) and reinstalled (`sudo apt install qgis`) qgis 3.12. When I open a new project I run into CRS issues when trying to add a vector. The vector's associated `*.prj` file has code that indicates the CRS should be 4269/NAD83. When I load the vector (`*.shp`) into the project, it has an "unknown projection". Any attempts to set the CRS either through the button in the bottom left, or through the layer properties fail.

If I go into the settings and try to check the `Prompt for CRS`, adding layers then opens the dialogue box for selecting a CRS, but selecting any CRS closes the dialogue momentarily, then the box reopens with no CRS selected. When this happens, I can only exit out of the dialogue by killing QGIS as a whole, usually using `xkill`.

I am on Linux Mint 19.3, using QGIS 3.12. The file I am trying to use can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WUsD-UIGeGjTdLBy7YSlBcPFT5XT8Vkx)

Update:

I completely removed qgis from my pc. After `apt remove qgis` `apt purge qgis` and `apt autoremove qgis`. I changed the QGIS source to the ltr (3.10), and reinstalled. The problem has gone away, and I can now set the CRS, and `*.shp` files import with the correct CRS. This isn't very helpful for future people that have this issue unfortunately.

Comment: I've downloaded your shape file and I can open it. There is one polygon in the layer near to Calgary. I use Ubuntu 18.04 and QGIS 3.12.1. There may be problem with QGIS proj definition (srs.db) or proj library, I guess. Try to check Settings/Optinos/CRS.

Comment: When I go into Settings/Options/CRS the default CRS option is No Projection. I am unable to change this. I can go into the tool to choose a new CRS, but any option I choose does not create any changes. When I add an OSM layer to the map, the polygon lines up with the arctic ocean in the OSM layer.